# Count and Groupby using linq from sql query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, google-visualization

Im trying to create a table that counts all orders and groups them in a table from sql to linq to use in a bar graph with google charts.

Table`

```
Orders  Status
8       Created
3       Delayed
4       Enroute
```

sql

```
SELECT Count (OrderID) as 'Orders', order_status FROM [ORDER]
where order_status ='Created'OR order_status= 'Delayed' OR order_status='Enroute'
group by order_status
```

controller

```
  public ActionResult GetChart()
    {
        var Orders = db.Order.Select(a => new { a.OrderID, a.order_status })
                             .GroupBy(a => a.order_status);

        return Json(Orders, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is not displaying the correct results as the linq seems to be wrong. 
can someone please point me in the right direction? I am relatively new to this.
thanks in advance.

Comment: From your example, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:-

```
var result = db.Order.Where(x => x.order_status == "Created"
                             ||  x.order_status == "Delayed"
                             ||  x.order_status == "Enroute")
                     .GroupBy(x => x.order_status)
                     .Select(x => new 
                                  {
                                       order_status = x.Key,
                                       Orders = x.Count()
                                  });
```

Or if you prefer query syntax then:-

```
var result = from o in db.Order
             where o.order_status == "Created" || o.order_status == "Delayed" 
                || o.order_status == "Enroute"
             group o by o.order_status
             select new 
                    {
                        orderStatus = x.Key,
                        Counts = x.Count()
                    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to group by `Status` and count total number of orders in each group (I build a simple console program to demonstrate). I suppose the data is:

```
Orders  Status
8       Created
3       Delayed
4       Enroute
2       Created
1       Delayed
```

**Order.cs**

```
public class Order
{
    public Order(int orderId, string status)
    {
        OrderId = orderId;
        Status = status;
    }

    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Data
        var orders = new List<Order>
        {
            new Order(8, "Created"),
            new Order(3, "Delayed"),
            new Order(4, "Enroute"),
            new Order(2, "Created"),
            new Order(1, "Delayed"),
        };

        // Query
        var query = orders
            .GroupBy(x => x.Status)
            .Select(x => new {Status = x.Key, Total = x.Count()});

        // Display
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Status + ": " + item.Total);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The one you need to focus in is `query`. After using `GroupBy`, you will have a list of groups. For each group, the `Key` is the criteria to group (here is the `Status`). Then, we call `Count()` to get the total number of element in that group.

So, from the program above, the output should be:

```
Created: 2
Delayed: 2
Enroute: 1
```